# Simple Injector Inject IEnumerable<Func<T>>

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, expression-trees, simple-injector

How Can I inject `IEnumerable<Func<T>>` using Simple Injector?

Just to add some context, I'm trying to create all EventHandlers that knows how to handle one specific Event. So here is my `Container` registration:

```
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IHandleDomainEvent<>),
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

And here Are two classes that implement the `IHandleEvent<T>` interface for the same Event:

```
public class Reservation : IHandleDomainEvent<OrderConfirmed>{}
public class Order: IHandleDomainEvent<OrderConfirmed>{}
```

So when I call the Simple Injector:

```
var handlers = _container.GetAllInstances<Func<IHandleDomainEvent<OrderConfirmed>>>();
```

I would like to Receive `IEnumerable<Func<IHandleDomainEvent<OrderConfirmed>>>`

Just to clarify, I know that if I call:

```
var handlers = _container.GetAllInstances<IHandleDomainEvent<OrderConfirmed>>();
```

I would get an `IEnumerable<IHandleDomainEvent<OrderConfirmed>>`.

---

For interfaces that have only one implementation, registering using:

```
container.Register(typeof(IHandleDomainEvent<>),
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

And adding the following ResolveUnregisteredType to the end of the registration:

```
container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (o, args) => ResolveFuncOfT(o, args, container);

// Function
private static void ResolveFuncOfT(object s, UnregisteredTypeEventArgs e, Container container)
{
    var type = e.UnregisteredServiceType;
    if (!type.IsGenericType || type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Func<>)) return;
    Type serviceType = type.GetGenericArguments().First();
    InstanceProducer producer = container.GetRegistration(serviceType, true);
    Type funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(serviceType);
    var factoryDelegate = Expression.Lambda(funcType, producer.BuildExpression()).Compile();
    e.Register(Expression.Constant(factoryDelegate));
}
```

Will allow calling:

```
var handler = _container.GetInstance<Func<IHandleDomainEvent<TEvent>>>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the beauty of Simple Injector: You'll never have to resolve an `IEnumerable<Func<T>>` because any `IEnumerable<T>` resolved by Simple Injector already functions as a *stream*.

This means that when you resolve an `IEnumerable<T>`, *none* of the elements of the stream will be resolved. They get only resolved when iterating the enumerable, and are resolved one-by-one.

When iterating the stream, elements will be resolved according to their lifestyle. This means that when the elements in the collection are `Transient` iterating the stream twice will cause the creation of new transient instances.

Example:

```
// Only resolves the enumerable, not the contained handlers.
// This enumerable itself is a singleton, you can reference it forever.
var collection = container.GetInstances<IEventHandler<OrderConfirmed>>();

// Calls back into the container to get the first element, but nothing more
var first = collection.First();

// Since the stream that Simple Injector returns is a IList<T>, getting the last
// element is an O(1) operation, meaning that only the last element is resolved;
// not the complete collection.
var last = collection.Last();

// Calling .ToArray(), however, will obviously resolve all registrations that are 
// part of the collection.
var all = collection.ToArray();

// Iterating a stream will always call back into the container, which ensures
// that the stream adheres to the elements lifestyles. Transients will be
// created on each iteration, while singletons will only be created once.
container.Register<Apple>(Lifestyle.Transient);
container.Register<Banana>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.RegisterCollection<IFruit>(typeof(Apple), typeof(Banana));
var fruits = container.GetAllInstances<IFruit>();
Assert.AreNotSame(fruits.First(), fruits.First());
Assert.AreSame(fruits.Last(), fruits.Last());

// Even other collection types such as IReadOnlyCollection<T> behave as streams
var col = container.GetInstance<IReadOnlyCollection<IEventHandler<OrderConfirmed>>();

// This gives you the possibility to get a particular item by its index.
var indexedItem = col[3];
```

You can find more information on working with collections in Simple Injector here:

- [Simple Injector Documentation - Using - Collection types](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html?highlight=stream#collection-types)
- [Simple Injector Documentation - Advanced - Auto-Registration](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=stream#batch-automatic-registration)
- [Simple Injector Documentation - Design Decisions -
  The API clearly differentiates the registration of collections](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decisions.html#separate-collections)
- [Simple Injector Documentation - Collections and lifetime management](https://simpleinjector.org/lifetimes+collections-and-lifetime-management)

Comment: Nice! But, I'm not shure it will help me. Because I need the simpleinjector to return me one instance each time the Func<T> is called. So, If I call (in your example) collection.First() twice, both instances will be the same.
In the End, the only way out I see is to create one class that opens a new Scope and inside this scope instantiate the class T. So each time I call it instantiate inside a new scope.

Comment: If you need a new instance every time you call first, make sure your hsndlers sre registered as Transient. You seem to have currently registered them either with Scoped or Singleton.